# Append variable to <script> react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to append two variables to a script tag in react.js. I have created the script tag in the head of the document like so:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

However, I wish to append two JS variables inside the `<script></script>` tags, so it is the following:

```
<script>
    var io_install_flash = false;
    var io_install_stm = false;
</script>
```

Comment: So you are trying to use script to append another script that defines two global variables?

Comment: No, I wish to add a script to the head of the document which defines two global variables.

Comment: Why would you need this :) http://xyproblem.info/ Why don't you use the first script to define those variables?

Comment: Because I am using a 3rd party and they required me to do this.

Comment: "I am using a 3rd party and they required me" required you to add a script? Or define variables?

Comment: I need to append a script tag with these variables to the head of the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148792/discussion-between-jbd-and-yury-tarabanko).

Answer (score 0):

The following code would add the script to head tag:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = `<script>
    var io_install_flash = false;
    var io_install_stm = false;
</script>`
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Though I didn't downvote because the direction might be right, this code wont work.